# MCI Command String can't play .wav when packaged release in vs2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, mcisendstring

It can't play .wav file when I packaged release project in vs2019, but it work in debug. I use the MCI Command String api. I have not idea. Does anyone have an idea?
This is code:
Open the wav

```
TemStr = "";
                TemStr = TemStr.PadLeft(127, Convert.ToChar(" "));
                CommandName = CommandName.PadLeft(260, Convert.ToChar(" "));
                mc.iName = value;
                ilong = GetShortPathName(mc.iName, CommandName, CommandName.Length);
                CommandName = GetCurrPath(CommandName);
                CommandName = "open " + mc.iName + " type MPEGVideo alias media ";//media
                ilong = mciSendString("close all", TemStr, TemStr.Length, 0);

                ilong = mciSendString(CommandName, TemStr, TemStr.Length, 0);

                durLength = "";
                durLength = durLength.PadLeft(128, Convert.ToChar(" "));

                ilong = mciSendString("set media time format milliseconds", TemStr, TemStr.Length, 0);

                mc.state = PlayModeEnum.Stop;
```

Play wav

```
TemStr = "";
            TemStr = TemStr.PadLeft(127, Convert.ToChar(" "));
            mciSendString("play media", TemStr, TemStr.Length, 0);
            
            mc.state = PlayModeEnum.Play;
```

I think code no problems in debug. It works. But can’t work in packaged release.

Comment: I think you need to provide some  code that did work and how did it work and why it fail and the error message. Otherwise it will guess work. Which framework do you use on Visual studio 2022.

Comment: I use the framework 4.6.1 in visual studio 2019. I attached the code just now.

Comment: So do you get error when it is in release

Comment: No. I didn’t  get any error message when it in release.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is it can’t install program files path. It is default path when use the setup project. So you need manual set the install path. Don’t use the default path.